# Why is this not a valid definition of dependent function types in agda?

Tags: lambda, types, agda

I was watching a lecture where the lecturer said that it was impossible, or at least very difficult to define Pi types in Agda. But I'm convinced there has to be a way. Given a type in a universe and a family from the type to the universe, any function from the type to some type in the family will be of the Pi type. So I thought it would make sense to use a lambda:

```
data Pi (A : Set) (B : A -> Set) : Set where
  \ (a : A) -> (b : B a) : Pi A B
```

When I try to load this it gives me a parse error. I'm not sure why, perhaps it doesn't want `\` to be a type constructor, but it kind of makes sense to consider a lambda to be a type constructor of a function type. Note that I am using the latex feature for Agda in Emacs but I don't think I can write latex in stack overflow. That being said, I tried replacing the lowercase lambda with an uppercase one to see if it wanted a unique type constructor, but to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by "define Pi types"? They are already in the language and used all the time.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I guess you call it a useless question but I'm just interested in what the definition would look like if it weren't built in

Comment: Your constructor has a pi type so you're not really adding anything new from smaller first principles.

Comment: My point is that this constructor (well, the correct one from @asr's answer below) needs to wrap something which is already a Pi type. If you didn't have Pi types, then you couldn't type the constructor.

Comment: @Cactus Yeah I see what you mean now

Answer (score 3):

You can use the uppercase lambda after fixing the typo in `: Pi A B`, that is

```
data Pi (A : Set) (B : A -> Set) : Set where
  Λ : ((a : A) -> B a) -> Pi A B
```